# Why 'SimSun' appeared in libreoffice font menu ,but no such font in os?

Tags: fonts

```
uname -a
Linux yyy 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

List all the Chinese fonts in my os.

```
fc-list |grep  "宋"
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic-gbsn00lp/gbsn00lp.ttf: AR PL SungtiL GB,文鼎ＰＬ简报宋:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic-bsmi00lp/bsmi00lp.ttf: AR PL Mingti2L Big5,文鼎ＰＬ細上海宋:style=Regular
fc-list |grep  "SimSun"
#Nothing as output of  command: fc-list |grep  "SimSun"
```

Now open a file with libreoffice in my os.

[image]
Why 'SimSun' appeared in  libreoffice font menu ,but no such font in os?

[image]

```
fc-list |grep -i "SimSun"
#Nothing as output for the above command too
```

Comment: The file name in not SimSun, but simsun : Please use "grep -i" →  `$ fc-list | grep -i SimSun` → (my example) `/usr/share/fonts/TTF/simsun.ttc: NSimSun,新宋体:style=Regular` ... `/usr/share/fonts/TTF/simsun.ttc: SimSun,宋体:style=Regular`

Comment: If you place the mouse pointer over the font name, Libreoffice displays the tooltip.
What is the tooltip message in your environment?
In my environment the message is `"Font Name. The current font is not available and will be replaced."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openoffice can detect file's font-family,if the font is not contained in os.
Font Name. The current font is not available and will be substituted with other font contained in os.

[image]

In my case the character displayed is not simsun.